# How to store the value of model in a variable?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-ngmodel

I am creating a directive, in which i want to compare the value stored in a model (say "name" as model and it is having value "Angular")
to be stored in a variable.

I tried something like below,

```
var nameValue=name;
```

but it(nameValue) is not having the value "Angular"

```
Example:

app.directive('kmRadio', function() {

  return{
    restrict:'E',
    compile: function(element,attrs) {
      var model=ngModelName;     

      console.info(attrs.kmModel);
      console.info("{{'+attrs.kmModel+'}}");

      if(attrs.kmTitle==model) {
        previewString="<input type="+"radio"+" checked>";
      }
      else {
        previewString="<input type="+"radio"+">";
      }

      var htmlText=''+previewString+''+

        element.replaceWith(htmlText);
    }
  }
})
```

Can anyone tell me how to retrieve the value stored in model(ng-model)

Comment: `scope.ngModel`? I suggest you post some code.

Answer (score 0):

You can link attributes in the directive scope to the parent with the `scope` attribute. A detailed explanation can be found here: [What is the difference between '@' and '=' in directive scope in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14050195/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-directive-scope)

In essence adding

return{
    restrict:'E',
    scope: {
       kmModel: '=kmModel'
    }
    compile: function(element,attrs) {
      var model=ngModelName;

```
  console.info(attrs.kmModel);
  console.info("{{'+attrs.kmModel+'}}");

  if(attrs.kmTitle==model) {
    previewString="<input type="+"radio"+" checked>";
  }
  else {
    previewString="<input type="+"radio"+">";
  }

  var htmlText=''+previewString+''+

    element.replaceWith(htmlText);
}
```

}

Would solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify things a bit with `ng-checked`, and a link function:

```
app.directive('kmRadio', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: true,
    replace: true,
    template: "<input type='radio' ng-checked='title == model' />",
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.model = scope.$eval(attrs.kmModel);
      scope.title = attrs.kmTitle;

      console.info('attrs.kmModel: ', attrs.kmModel);
      console.info('scope.$eval(attrs.kmModel):', scope.model);
    }
  }
})
```

Here is a working demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/owTLnPUbbZIhwUtfoivt?p=preview